# Running my multivariable function for several vectors?

Tags: r, variables, mapply, auc

I have the following dataframe with 6 columns and several thousand rows.

Example:
[Screenshot of example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELMXf.png)

Each column represents a different timepoint 0,1,3,6,9,12. I want to calculate the area under the curve for each row of values.
For example for row 1, I would use the following function from the DescTools package

```
x=c(0,1,3,6,9,12)

y=c(130, 125, 120, 115, 108, 115)

AUC(x, y, method = c("linear"), na.rm=FALSE)
```

Is there a way to create a new variable which is the AUC for each row from my dataframe?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` to do rowwise

```
library(DescTools)
i1 <- rowSums(!is.na(df1)) >2
df1$AUC[i1] <- apply(df1[i1,], 1, FUN = function(y) 
        AUC(x, y, method = "linear", na.rm = FALSE))
df1$AUC[i1]
[1] 1394 1518
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(col1 = c(130, 140), col2 = c(125, 137), col3 = c(120, 
125), col4 = c(115, 120), col5 = c(108, 125), col6 = c(115, 130
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
x <- c(0,1,3,6,9,12)
```

Comment: I tried your code: it gives following error: error in AUC(x, y, method = "linear", na.rm = FALSE) : 
  length x must equal length y

Comment: @ABCD I assumed that your `x` vector is equal to the number of columns of the dataset 'df1'

Comment: @ABCD Your description says `have the following dataframe with 6 columns`

Comment: That works for the dataframe you created. My actual data contains a few NA. And i now get the following error:
Error during wrapup: need at least two non-NA values to interpolate
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart

Comment: @ABCD I checked that as well `y=c(130, 125, 120, 115, 108, NA); AUC(x, y, method = c("linear"), na.rm=FALSE)
[1] NA` returns NA

Comment: @ABCD that error will be because you don't have at least 2 non-NA per row.  what do you want to return for those cases

Comment: @ABCD try the update